# ¿Como eliminar los articulos con el mismo boton que los agrega?

Tags: javascript, html, css

El código funciona y al hacer click en confirmar compra los productos se agregan al carrito pero cuando se hace click de nuevo en el mismo botón para eliminar el o los productos seleccionados, salta un error por consola que evita que se haga tal acción.

No encuentro la solucion para eliminar con el mismo boton los elementos adecuadamente, se puede eliminar con otro boton donde se agregan, pero no con el mismo boton.

Quisiera saber como hallo la solucion del codigo.

El código funciona y al hacer click en confirmar compra los productos se agregan al carrito pero cuando se hace click de nuevo en el mismo botón para eliminar el o los productos seleccionados, salta un error por consola que evita que se haga tal acción.

No encuentro la solucion para eliminar con el mismo boton los elementos adecuadamente, se puede eliminar con otro boton donde se agregan, pero no con el mismo boton.

Quisiera saber como hallo la solucion del codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./images/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carrito</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<style>
    .modal-body {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .div-items .items:last-child {
        border-bottom: none !important;
    }

    .delete-product,
    .btn-add-cart {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .card-items .item{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

   /*  .items{
        transform: translateX(-110%);
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .items.trans{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    } */
</style>

<body>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Plan Personalizado</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="w-50 border-end border-secondary p-4">
                        <h4 class=" text-center">Tu lista de servicios <span class="count-product">0</span></h4>
                        <div class="card-items">
                            <!-- <div class=" d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                <div class=" d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check px-3"></i>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Creación de página no code</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="px-3">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark delete-product"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-50 p-4" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                        <p>
                            Selecciona los servicios para iniciar a configurar tu plan personalizado:
                        </p>
                        <div class="mb-4 div-items products">
                            <h5>Soluciones Técnicas</h5>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 1
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">100</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="1"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 2
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">200</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="2"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 3
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">300</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="3"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4 div-items products">
                            <h5>Soluciones Técnicas</h5>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 4
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">400</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="4"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 5
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">500</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="5"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                class=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-bottom py-2 ps-3 items">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="itemcart-title">
                                        Creación de página no code 6
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="price">600</span>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus px-3 btn-add-cart" data-id="6"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <h4>Costo del plan: $<strong class="price-total">0</strong> /mes</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        let allContainerCart = document.querySelectorAll('.products');
        let containerBuyCart = document.querySelector('.card-items');
        let priceTotal = document.querySelector('.price-total')
        let amountProduct = document.querySelector('.count-product');


        let buyThings = [];
        let totalCard = 0;
        let countProduct = 0;

        //functions
        loadEventListenrs();
        function loadEventListenrs() {

            allContainerCart.forEach(elem => {
                elem.addEventListener('click', addProduct)
            })

            containerBuyCart.addEventListener('click', deleteProduct);
        }

        function addProduct(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-add-cart')) {
                const selectProduct = e.target.parentElement;
                readTheContent(selectProduct);
            }
        }

        function deleteProduct(e) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-product')) {
                const deleteId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');

                buyThings.forEach(value => {
                    if (value.id == deleteId) {
                        let priceReduce = parseFloat(value.price);
                        totalCard = totalCard - priceReduce;
                        totalCard = totalCard.toFixed(2);
                    }
                });

                buyThings = buyThings.filter(product => product.id !== deleteId);

                countProduct--;
            }
            //FIX: El contador se quedaba con "1" aunque ubiera 0 productos
            if (buyThings.length === 0) {
                priceTotal.innerHTML = 0;
                amountProduct.innerHTML = 0;
            }

            loadHtml();
        }

        function readTheContent(product) {
            const infoProduct = {
                title: product.querySelector('.itemcart-title').textContent,
                price: product.querySelector('.price').textContent,
                id: product.querySelector('.btn-add-cart').getAttribute('data-id'),
                icon: product.querySelector('.btn-add-cart')
            }

            const exist = buyThings.some(product => product.id === infoProduct.id);
            if (exist) {
                buyThings = [...buyThings];
                totalCard = parseFloat(totalCard);
                totalCard = totalCard.toFixed(2);
                infoProduct.icon.classList.replace("fa-circle-plus","fa-circle-minus")
                /* infoProduct.icon.classList.replace("btn-add-cart","delete-product") */
            } else {
                buyThings = [...buyThings, infoProduct]

                totalCard = parseFloat(totalCard) + parseFloat(infoProduct.price);
                totalCard = totalCard.toFixed(2);
                countProduct++;
                infoProduct.icon.classList.replace("fa-circle-plus","fa-circle-minus")
                /* infoProduct.icon.classList.replace("btn-add-cart","delete-product") */
            }

            
            
            loadHtml();

        }

        function loadHtml() {
            clearHtml();
            buyThings.forEach(product => {
                const { title, id } = product;
                const row = document.createElement('div');
                row.classList.add('item');
                row.innerHTML = `
                    <div class=" d-flex align-items-center">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check px-3"></i>
                        <p class="mb-0">${title}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="" >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark px-3 delete-product" data-id="${id}"></i>               
                    `; 

                containerBuyCart.appendChild(row);

                priceTotal.innerHTML = totalCard;

                amountProduct.innerHTML = countProduct;
            });
        }
        function clearHtml() {
            containerBuyCart.innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56f48dccb3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pues en programación hay algo que se llama *Principio de Responsabilidad Única*. Querer usar el mismo botón para varias acciones viola gravemente ese principio. Lo propio es tener dos botones, luego, en la lógica de tu programa, puedes **mostrar** el botón `Borrar` cuando **sólo** se necesite borrar y al revés, mostrar `Agregar` cuando **sólo** se agregar. ¿Y si se necesitan ambas cosas? Pues muestras tus dos botones.

Comment: yo no veo ningún error por consola